# How do I format in Java?

Tags: java

How do I format different parts separately? Here is my problem statement:

Modify the statement

```
        outFile.println(fName + lName + score1 + score2 + score3 +
                (score1 + score2 + score3)/3.0);
```

So that the lines in the output.txt are properly formatted (fName and lName in left justified in 10 spaces , score1, score2 and score3 right justified in 4 spaces and average in right justified 6 spaces (2 decimal places));

Comment: What should the output look like?  Please show an example.

Comment: You can read documentation about `java.util.Formatter`. This features are available in your `PrintWriter.printf` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.format(format, args...)`.

`String` documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

More about format syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: Or `outFile.printf()` if `outFile` is a `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is likely what you're after.

(Assuming the scores are ints)

```
String.format("%-10s%-10s%4d%4d%4d%6.2f", fname, lname, score1, score2, score3, ((double)(score1 + score2 + score3) / 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `format` method of the `PrintWriter` class - you don't need to explicitly format this into a `String` before you print it.

```
outFile.format( format-string, fname, lname, score1, score2, score3);
```

Check the Javadocs for [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and for [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to work out what `format-string` should be.  Don't forget the `%n` at the end of the format string, so that you get a newline character.